# An inequality about 2-dimensional normal random variable with a negative correaltion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Suppose $(X,Y)$~$N$($0$,$0$,$\sigma_1^2$,$\sigma_2^2$,$\rho$), where $\rho<0$.

How to prove for any positive number $a,b$, $P[X≥a,Y≥b]≤P[X≥a]P[Y≥b]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at  [E. H. Lehmann's  "Some Concepts of Dependence",](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177699260)  *Ann. Math. Statist.*,  Volume 37, Number 5 (1966), 1137-1153, which contains your result.